# Is this dynamic SQL query generation safe from injections?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

Is there something that may escape the sanitation in my script or is it safe from *most* SQL injections? The way I understand it, if you pass query as prepared argument, it does not matter how the query was build, right?

Edit2: I edited the code to reflect the suggestions of binding the $_POST values

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table');
$q->execute();
$data = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$key = array();
foreach ($data as $word){
    array_push($key,$word['Field']);
    } 
$sqlSub= "INSERT INTO other_table(";
$n = 0;
foreach ($key as $index){
    $sqlSub = $sqlSub.$index.", ";
    $n = $n + 1;
}
$sqlSub = $sqlSub.") VALUES (";
for ($i=1; $i<$n;$i++){
    $sqlSub = $sqlSub."?, ";
}
$sqlSub = $sqlSub.."?)";
$keyValues = array();
for($i=0;i<n;$i++){
    array_push($keyValues,$_POST[$key[$i]]);
}
$q->$pdo->prepare($sqlSub);
q->execute($keyValues);
```

EDIT: This is how the final query looks like after suggested edits

```
INSERT INTO other_table($key[0],...,$key[n]) VALUES (?,...,nth-?);
```

Comment: `if you pass query as prepared argument, it does not matter how the query was build`...wrong. Yes, this is still vulnerable. In fact, you are just as vulnerable as if you didn't prepare the query. The way to make this sql injection safe is not to just prepare your query, but to prepare the query with placeholders and bind values to those placeholders.

Comment: No! If you're not using binding your values, you're not safe.

Comment: no, if you want to make it safe get a list of the columns in the table using 'Describe' or 'Explain'  array keys could be changed if they are the name of the form inputs for example, with a list of columns you can cross check them.  Then use prepared statements for the values, and a white list for the keys.

Comment: @aynber but they are using prepared statements. They are just using concatenation, not bind with it. Prepared statements are no more secure than standard sql if you don't bind.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I amended my comment with that. Because to me, prepared statements means binding, but that's only how I've trained my brain.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I understand the `?` parameter binding, but I am having trouble to figuring out how then execute the query with `execute(array($_POST[$key],..., $_POST[$nthkey]);` since the number of `$_POST` arguments can differ between `tables` and they are order dependant

Comment: loop over the post values like you are doing here, but instead of concatenating a string, append them to a different array. Pass that array into execute.

Comment: What does the sqlSub value output?  actually it looks fairly secure, but without seeing that I cant be sure, your using `show` for the column names, and maybe a placeholder with the index value added, but Its to mish mash to tell without seeing the query.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - that may be the case, there is no execute here.  `$sqlSub.$index` this is not the value but the placeholder.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I was commenting on their comment above mine where they were asking how to pass in a dynamic number of arguments to execute.

Comment: I know, but eveyone is quick to the jump, and without seeing what the query is, its hard to tell, if there are or are not placeholders, but I would expect to see a `:` in there somewhere :)

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, `$sqlSub = $sqlSub.$_POST[$key[$i-1]].", ";` is litterally concatenating the values straight from $_POST. You are reading the part where they are building the column list.

Comment: in anycase without execute it wont work ;-/

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix yes, you are correct, preparing a query without executing it is completely sql injection safe.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I added the resulting query that is prepared and the obviously executed, I just did not add the execute itself in code snipper

Comment: I actually have a DB class that is similar concept, except it's 100% safe, with placeholders, and schema checking on the columns :)

Comment: @TheLaw - It's not Safe! ... you should use the keys with `:key_index` as placeholder build a second array with same keys and the values to use in the execute statement.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix okay, I will do just that, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I edited my question, would the changes do?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The example code shown is *not* safe from most SQL Injections.

You understanding is entirely wrong.

What matters is the SQL text. If that's being dynamically generated using potentially unsafe values, then the SQL text is vulnerable.

---

The code is vulnerable in multiple places. Even the names of the columns are potentially unsafe.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
( `Robert'; DROP TABLE Students; --`  VARCHAR(2)
, `O``Reilly`                         VARCHAR(2)
);

SHOW COLUMNS FROM foo

FIELD                             TYPE        NULL
--------------------------------  ----------  ----
Robert'; DROP TABLE Students; --  varchar(2)  YES
O`Reilly                          varchar(2)  YES
```

You would need to enclose the column identifiers in backticks, after escaping any backtick within the column identifier with another backtick.

Comment: How are the names of the columns unsafe, since those are fetched directly from un-mutable table server-side, without user input? Plus I edited my post

Comment: I show an example of how the column identifiers can be unsafe for inclusion in SQL text, and require special handling to make them safe. This  is why you see mysqldump and all sorts of MySQL tools wrapping identifiers in backticks, even when the backticks aren't required. (It's just faster to always do that, than do a check whether it's required or not.)

Comment: Now I see. If I also allowed users to create their own table schema and then allowed them to run this script, they could do exactly what you say through column names. Makes sense, good point.

Comment: The column names can't be passed as bind parameters. To handle those, you need to properly escape them,  something like... **`'\`' . str_replace( $colname, '\`','\`\`') . '\`'`**  before including it as an identifier in the SQL text.  I think the rest of your code is following best practice, using static `?` bind placeholders for values, and supplying the actual values as bind parameters, not as part of the SQL text.

Comment: Of course, the column-names should **always** be *fixed.* Never allow user input to directly determine what tables and/or columns are to be manipulated. Don't let users "create their own tables."

Comment: @MikeRobinson There are few exceptions. For example when you want to let  user to define content structure which is generated around table columns, you have to allow them to build a table. But of course, that should always be sanitized and only administrative users should ever be allowed to do that, preferably in form that is hidden behind multiple authentication measures. I agree on that allowing normal user to even get near DB is bad idea

Comment: In cases like that, I prefer to store "the user's 'tabular' data" in *some other way,* than to allow them to directly build a table. If they *can* "build a table," then I certainly want to create for them a separate *database* in which they can monkey.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, make sure your column names are safe.

SQL injection can occur from *any* external input, not just http request input. You can be at risk if you use content read from a file, or from a web service, or from a function argument from other code, or the return value of other code, or even from your own database... *trust nothing!* :-)

You could make sure the column names themselves are escaped. Unfortunately, there is no built-in function to do that in most APIs or frameworks. So you'll have to do it yourself with regular expressions.

I also recommend you learn about PHP's builtin array functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). A lot of your code could be quicker to develop the code, and it will probably better runtime performance too.

Here's an example:

```
function quoteId($id) {
  return '`' . str_replace($id, '`', '``') . '`';
}

$q = $pdo->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_table");
while ($field = $q->fetchColumn()) {
  $fields[] = $field;
}

$params = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fields));
$fieldList = implode(",", array_map("quoteId", array_keys($params)));
$placeholderList = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($params), "?"));
$sqlSub = "INSERT INTO other_table ($fieldList) VALUES ($placeholderList)";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sqlSub);
$q->execute($params);
```

In this example, I intersect the columns from the table with the post request parameters. This way I use only those post parameters that are also in the set of columns. It may end up producing an INSERT statement in SQL with fewer than all the columns, but if the missing columns have defaults or allow NULL, that's okay.

Answer (score -1):

There is exactly **one** way to prevent SQL injection: to make sure that the **text** of your query-string *never* includes user-supplied content, no matter how you may attempt to 'sanitize' it.

When you use "placeholders," as suggested, the **text** of the SQL string contains *(probably ...)* question marks ... `VALUES (?, ?, ?)` to indicate each place where a parameter is to be inserted. A corresponding list of *parameter values* is supplied **separately**, each time the query is executed.

Therefore, even if value supplied for `last_name` is `"tables; DROP TABLE STUDENTS;"`, SQL will *never* see this as being "part of the SQL string." It will simply insert that *"most-unusual `last_name`"* into the database.

If you are doing *bulk* operations, the fact that you need prepare the statement only *once* can save a considerable amount of time. You can then execute the statement as many times as you want to, passing a different (or, the same) set of parameter-values to it each time.